# Create Popup Menu Separator Programmatically - Android

Tags: android

Create Popup Menu Separator Programmatically - Android
Im having problem with adding separator programmatically in programmatically created Popup Menu.
In xml I think its automatic but when I search for method I cant seem to find something like `popmenu.getMenu().addSeparator();`

Is this possible?

This is what I tried:

```
    int group_id = 0;
    int item_id = 1;
    int order = 1;
    PopupMenu popupMenu  = new PopupMenu(this , btn_add_product);
    popupMenu.getMenu().add( group_id , item_id , order , "Sample");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add("---------------------------------------");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### My answer is not logical or True

---

i don't know how to do it programmatic

**here by ~ID_GROUP~ .xml** --- Dynamic

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_1" />
</group>

<group android:id="@+id/grp2" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_2" />
</group>
```

~
i do programmatic with little fix 
if that help you of some thing
.**setEnabled**(*false*)

```
    // add(groupId, itemId, order, title);
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Option1").setShortcut('1', 'a');
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Option2").setShortcut('2', 'b');
    menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Option3").setShortcut('3', 'c');

    /**
     * If you're running your code on Android 3.0+, the icons in the menu are not shown by design.
     * menu.add(0, 3, 3, "").setEnabled(false).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_bookmark);
     */
    menu.add(0, 3, 3, "______________________________________").setEnabled(false);

    menu.add(1, 4, 4, "Option1-2").setShortcut('5', 'd');
    menu.add(1, 5, 5, "Option2-2").setShortcut('6', 'e');
    menu.add(1, 6, 6, "Option3-2").setShortcut('7', 'f');
```

this just to support or give help .

Comment: ah yes that will do, `setEnabled`